# Conversion of SQL Update clause into ElasticSearch Update

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I would like to do the following update query on my ES index called "avails-ingest-history". How would I do the below in ES?

```
UPDATE `avails-ingest-history` 
SET is_hidden = False
WHERE transaction_guid='XXX'
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
body = {
  "script": {
    "is_hidden": False
  },

  "query": {
    "match": {
      "guid": "xxx"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I wasn't sure about the `script` key or whether an exact match uses the `match` term.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the preferred way to do the above, but here is the way that I'm currently using:

```
body = {
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.is_hidden=false"
  },
  
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "guid": "xxx"
    }
  }
}
self.es.update_by_query(body=body, doc_type='_doc', index='avails-ingest-history')
```

I am open to better ways to accomplish the above.